# while set property "command timeout" in sql connection string it showing Keyword not supported from my web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

while set property "command timeout" in SQL connection string it showing Keyword not supported from my web application. Moreover unable to add Package reference `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` v5.1.0.

I want to update the connection string in order to set the command timeout 90 - keep in mind that this will apply to my entire application, unless overridden in code by setting the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property.

This is my code in web.config

```
<add name="constr_local" connectionString="data source=(local);initial catalog=SCMS;persist security info=False;user id=sa;password=111;max pool size=5000;connect timeout=60000;command timeout=90" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```